# Jquery convert contents of .parent() to string

Tags: jquery, append

I have a variable (parentTR) declared as follows:

```
parentTR = selectedTD.parent();
```

and I would like to merge the HTML content that makes up parentTR into another variable ownerData. I have done this as follows:

```
var ownerData = '<div><table><tr><th>Table header</th><thTable header</th><th>Table header</th><th>Table header</th><th>Table header</th></tr>';
ownerData += parentTR;
ownerData += "</div>";
$('.ownerResults').append($(ownerData).clone()).html();
```

However this displays:

```
<div>[object Object]
<table><tr><th>Table header</th><thTable header</th><th>Table header</th><th>Table header</th><th>Table header</th></tr>
</div>
```

How do I convert parentTR to a string for this instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.parent()` returns a jQuery object. You need to use its `.html()` method to get HTML content as string:

```
ownerData += parentTR.html();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the complete markup you can use

```
parentTR.text();
```

and to get only the contents of the tag you can use

```
parentTR.html();
```